# What is a good and easy way to build a website with multiple real-time projects on different pages using node.js, socket.io, express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I want to build a website where I can host some little projects like games and such that I have made with node.js and socket.io and maybe other things in the future. I want them all to be hosted at the same time on the same server so someone can view them. I'm asking for advice on how to manage the code and files the best and what practices to use so:

**1.** I want the different apps not to interfere with each other. So the socket messages and stuff should not conflict unless I want to communicate across them but I don't need that for now.

**2.** I want my code to be structured and organised well so I can easily develop different projects independently and not have to worry much about the other stuff once i have done it.

**3.** I want the solution to be light both on the client (so not load anything not needed for the one thing they are viewing like libraries and data from the other apps) and on the server (so not wasting much resources on apps that aren't used at the moment)

Right now I'm using node.js runtime, express for the http server(routing, mvc, whatever else), socket.io for real-time communication and some other client side libraries for visualisation and such. I would prefer a solution with these but if there is something better I'm open to suggestions.